# Test drawable resource with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, bitmapfactory

In a unit test I would like to check whether a drawable resource (png image given by a resource id), has a fixed dimension and is transparent. My test class looks like:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class PngTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testGetPieceImageResource() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap bmp = 
       BitmapFactory.decodeResource(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources(),
                              getImageResource(), options);

    assertEquals( bmp.getWidth(), 64 );
    assertEquals( bmp.getHeight(), 64 );
    }
}
```

The test fails since `bmp.getWidth == bmp.getHeight == 100`. It seems that whatever I do, bitmapfactory always gives me a 100x100 bitmap irrespective of the original bitmap.The drawable myimage.png is in the drawable-nodpi folder, but the same problem appears if it is in the drawable folder.

Also `Color.alpha(bmp.getPixel(x,y));` appears to be 0 (i.e. transparent as far as I understand) for all combinations of (x,y) which I tried. So I get a fully transparent 100x100 bitmap which is not what the original bitmap looks like.

This test is meant to test a method which returns a resource id. Basically I would like to test whether this method returns the correct id (i.e. whether the corresponding png file matches the expected dimension/transparency). The actual code for the method does not matter, but as an example it could look like:

```
public int getImageResource() {
    if ( /* some condition */ {
        return R.drawable.myimage;
    } else {
        return R.drawable.anotherimage;
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on where to look for an error.

Comment: Just a random thought - I would be incredibly weary of performing this type of test in a robolectric test. It seems much better suited for a UI test suite like espresso because you are relying on an actual context and resource loading. Robolectric does some magical behind-the-scenes work to get you a fake context. Maybe try moving the test to be a robolectric test and seeing if that has any effect.

Comment: I also don't understand what are you testing - Android code itself? Or it is just part of code from you method that does some bitmap manipulation?

Comment: Sorry for incompleteness. I test a method which returns a resource id. Added some more information above. Perhaps indeed this would be better done with espresso?